# Java - NoClassDefFoundError on starting up local version of DynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, path, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to start [local version of DynamoDB](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/09/dynamodb-local-for-desktop-development.html) on the command line (OSX) using the following command as specified in the documentation:

```
java –Djava.library.path=. -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar
```

But getting the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: �Djava/library/path=/
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: �Djava.library.path=.
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: It seems the dash is actually an en-dash or some other variation(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#En_dash). Try retyping the entire command to make sure you are using the correct (i.e. 'normal') hyphen '-'.

Answer (score 0):

The � shows that it may be a character, which looks like hyphen '-' . Please inspect this.
Also, whenever you are using -D option, its best practice to use a complete jar name (rather than wild card). This will make sure that you are missing nothing.